# Does any one knows about Family Tree using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, family-tree, genealogy

Does any one know about any script that will work like http://www.genoom.com family tree?

Or can you guys give me any ideas about the database table structure they used to make the tree like this?

And how are they displaying family member boxes and lines?

Please let me know ASAP.

**[EDITED]**

I have tried table structure like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
TREE
-----------------------------------------------
ID | PARENTID | PARENT_RELATION | NAME
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 0        |                 | My Father 
2  | 1        | Father          | It is me
```

*tree(id int auto increment, parentid int, parent_relation varchar, name varchar)*

In first record it shows tree will starts with 'My Father' and then traverse and will display 'It is me'. And whole thing I tried in PHP by using a recursive function. But I stuck when I am trying to display connecting lines between nodes.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: Don't mean to be pedantic, but you don't "make" anything like this "in AJAX". The term AJAX describes a group of methods, not a language or environment. I guess what you're after is Javascript, but you're question is likely still too vague to receive good answers. You'll have to give us some more information…

Comment: I have tried table structure like this 
tree(id int auto increment, parentid int, parent_relation varchar, name varchar)
example: Record1:- 1, 0, '', 'My Father' Record2:- 2, 1, 'father', 'Its me'
In first record it shows tree will starts with 'My Father' and then traverse and will display 'Its me'. And whole thing I tried in PHP by using a recursive function. But I stuck when I am trying to display connecting lines between nodes.

Comment: Is your problem with the database or with displaying the data? Be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

you'd best reform your question to "is there a javascript framework for generating genealogy diagrams and datamapping", i'm on the lookout myself but didn't find anything good yet unless you use a general graphing framework like raphael but then you'r on your own with the modelling and datamapping etc.

EDIT: i have found this fiddle that looks very promising, it shows a way to connect two nodes with a simple model. http://jsfiddle.net/mking/2UJcZ/4/

I found also this similar solution using Go.js

http://gojs.net/latest/intro/usingModels.html

Comment: For that matter, GoJS has a simple family tree sample to start from: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/familyTree.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any open-source or paid scripts that use Ajax. There are [a few that use JavaScript](http://www.gensoftreviews.com/index.php?s=javascript) that might give you some ideas.

The one framework I know of that is freely available and is quite comprehensive is [Family.Show](http://familyshow.codeplex.com/), which might give you some good ideas as to how to set everything up. However, it uses Windows Presentation Foundation and Silverlight. Several different genealogy programs have sprouted from the Family.Show framework.